# What is the range of a Flaming Skull's spitfire attack?

Tags: monsters, pathfinder-2e, ranged-attack

In pathfinder 2, a [Flaming Skull](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=1078) has a ranged attack called spitfire:

> Ranged [one-action] spitfire +10 [+6/+2] (agile, fire), Damage 1d12+2 fire

What is the range increment for this attack?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## **There isn’t one listed, but it is *almost certainly* 20 feet.**

This is almost certainly an editing error or oversight - it happens from time to time, and likely won’t be fixed until and unless the monster gets reprinted.

*However*, in the *Mantle of Gold* adventure (Book one of *Sky King's Tomb*, there is a *variant* Flaming Skull introduced, the **Sporeborn Skull**.

The Sporeborn Skull has the following Ranged Attack:

> **Ranged** [One Action] Spittle +10 [+6 / +2] (Acid, Agile, Range Increment 20 feet), **Damage** 1d12+2 Acid.

Other than swapping out Fire for Acid damage, this ability is identical to the Flaming Skull's spitfire. The Sporeborn Skull shares a level with the Flaming Skull, and it's other attacks follow a similar pattern of being numerically equivalent, with fire swapped for poison/acid.

Given the clear range definition on the variant, I'd use that for the base monster as well.